# Getting a value from dynamic table cell and passing its value to a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I use JavaScript to dynamically create a table. I want to get the value of `stationIdCell` in order to pass it to the `refreshMETAR()` function. However, I can't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my table

```
const metarTableElement = document.querySelector('#metar_table')
const rowCount = metarTableElement.rows.length

if(rowCount > 6)
{
  metarTableElement.deleteRow(rowCount - 1)
} else {

  const row = metarTableElement.insertRow(1)

  var stationIdCell = row.insertCell(0)
  stationIdCell.innerHTML = `<button onclick="refreshMETAR(this.innerHTML)">${station_id}</button>`
  //I want to pass this value to the function

  var latitudeCell = row.insertCell(1)
  latitudeCell.innerHTML = `${latitude}`

  var longitudeCell = row.insertCell(2)
  longitudeCell.innerHTML = `${longitude}`

  var rawMETARCell = row.insertCell(3)
  rawMETARCell.innerHTML = `${raw_metar}`
```

Here's the function I want to pass the cell value to:

```
const refreshMETAR = () => {

  const stationElement    = this.innerHTML //The value of the table cell should be read here
  const station           = stationElement.value
  const alertPanelElement = document.querySelector('#alert_panel')

  console.log(`entered: ${station}`)

  validateADDSStation(station)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {

      let icao = null
      let site = null
      try{
        icao = json.response.data[0].Station[0].station_id[0]
        site = json.response.data[0].Station[0].site[0]
      } catch(err) {
        alertPanelElement.classList.remove('w3-hide')
        alertPanelElement.classList.add('w3-show')
        stationElement.focus()
        stationElement.select()
        console.log("BAD CODE")
      }

      console.log(`RETURN VALUE FROM VALIDATE: ${icao}`)
      if( station !== icao){
        console.log(`ICAO ${icao} not found`)
        alertPanelElement.classList.remove('w3-hide')
        alertPanelElement.classList.add('w3-show')
      }
      else {
        alertPanelElement.classList.remove('w3-show')
        alertPanelElement.classList.add('w3-hide')

        fetch(`${ADDS_METAR_URL}${station}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {

            // printValues(json)
            updateWeatherOutput(json, site)

        })
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: did you try this "const refreshMETAR = (htmlContent) => {...}"

Comment: @Rumesh could you please elaborate a little bit more on what you're saying? Should I keep `this.innerHTML`? Because I just tried that and it keeps returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to send params station_id into function refreshMETAR as params to send a request when the button clicked.
there're 2 problems in your code.

1. `<button onclick="refreshMETAR(this.innerHTML)">${station_id}</button>`
   i think this in above statement will be reference to window, not button element nor stationIdCell element.
2. `const refreshMETAR = () => { const stationElement = this.innerHTML //The value of the table cell should be read here`  you send (this.innerHtml) as in params ,yet this is not the way to use a in param

please try this:

```
stationIdCell.innerHTML = `<button onclick="refreshMETAR('${stationId}')">${station_id}</button>`

const refreshMETAR = (stationId) => {
    const station = stationId
    console.log(`entered: ${station}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

typical case of event delegation

first part:

```js
// GLOBAL
const metarTableElement = document.querySelector('#metar_table')
 
document.addEventListener('click', refreshMETAR )


//...
let rowCount = metarTableElement.rows.length
if (rowCount > 6)
  {
  metarTableElement.deleteRow( --rowCount )
  }
else 
  {
  let row = metarTableElement.insertRow()

  row.insertCell().innerHTML   = `<button class="cl_METAR">${station_id}</button>`
  row.insertCell().textContent = latitude
  row.insertCell().textContent = longitude
  row.insertCell().textContent = raw_metar
//...
```

on buttons clicks...

```js
function refreshMETAR(evt)
  {
  if (!evt.target.matches('button.cl_METAR')) return  // reject clicks from somewhere else 

  const station =  evt.target.textContent // === value in ${station_id}

  // ...

  }
```